# Problem getting "Invalid characters in string" in watch window during debugging VS2019 C++

Tags: c++, string, debugging, watch

```
    // Test of "Invalid characters in string"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>    
int main()
{
    char ac[100] =  "Hello World!  Åke Österman\n";
    std::string s = ac;
    printf (ac);
}
```

When using characters outside a-Z in strings I get this "Invalid characters in string" in the watch window.
I have no problem with the '�' used when I watch the the sting as an array.
Very frustrating when I just what to check I have the correct string.
What to do?  Any suggestions ? Setting "locale" for the debugger or what ???   :)

Comment: The microsoft compiler is sensitive to the file encoding and to the code page in effect during compilation. As the very first thing, you need to figure out both of these details. Do you see correct characters when you run the program in the console? What is the console code page?

Comment: There's no need to set locale. Just tested in VS2019 and debugger has no problems showing those characters. When do you inspect `s` variable? Setting break point too early (on `std::string s = ac` line which is before `s` is assigned) can cause such behavior.

Comment: Why are you using `printf`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce on VS2022 either. More exactly the *Invalid characters in string* message in only displayed before the variables receive their values, but the Unicode characters are correctly displayed after the initialization.

Comment: I find it very strange that you cant reproduce. The hex code for the two  characters in my example has the correct ANSI codes 0xC5 and 0xD6  An A with a small circle,  and an O with to dots.

Comment: I find it very strange that you can't reproduce. The hex code for the two  characters in my example has the correct ANSI codes 0xC5 and 0xD6  An A with a small circle,  and an O with to dots.     When I put a breakpoints at the end, and put the mouse on the original string I get the correct string plus  "Invalid characters in string" message.     If I put the mouse at "s" or "ac" I get only "Invalid characters in string" message as I get in the watch window.        Time out 5 minutes   :(

Comment: Have you tried to create a new empty console project, and put that code in it? If the problem disappear, then it was just a project config problem. If it persists, then you'll have to investigate further. BTW what is your system declared locale? Mine is French, but I use English language in MSVC (to be able to see the English names in menus...)

Comment: These are not "ANSI codes" by any stretch of imagination. These are codes from Windows-1252 code page.

Comment: My example is a "brand new standard console application".
My system is "very English" except for the Swedish keyboard.   
This is not a new problem for me. Have had it in several version of VS. And on different systems. It has frustrated me for years but now I am creating an application that is working with Swedish text so it is very inconvenient to have this problem.  :(    
Do you have any suggestion about how "to investigate further"
     
About "ANSI":
http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html

Comment: Don't believe everything you read on the Internet. There is a lot of misinformation out there. What you have linked is misinformation. CP-1252 has no relationship with ANSI, except that the first 128 characters of it coincide with ASCII, which is an ANSI-published standard that specifies a *seven bit encoding*. CP-1252 is not the only 8-bit encoding with this property, there are dozens more, and none has anything to do with ANSI. Not everyone uses CP-1252. I am using CP-65001, which is a UTF-8 code page.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. : ANSI as the published standard is indeed a 7 bit charset. But in all Windows docs, ANSI is the local 8 bits code page for Windows applications. And for most Western European language, Windows uses by default CP-1252 which is a variation of ISO-8859-1 aka Latin1 using some unaffected codes for accented or special characters having a unicode codepoint above 256.

Comment: If you want to parse Swedish-language files, you need to decide (1) whether you want to read and write CP-1252 or ISO/IEC 8859-1 (a.k.a. Latin-1) or UTF-8 or all of them and (2) how you want to represent your characters internally after you read them. These are your real problems. The "invalid character" annoyance is the least of your worries. If you decide to switch to UTF-8 or use wchar_t internally, it just magically disappears. If you are developing for Windows only, using wchar_t is probably the easiest way to get rid of all the annoyances.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yeah, Microsoft also calls this "ANSI" and it bugs me.

Comment: As I could not reproduce the annoying behaviour, I really have no genius idea. If you have an unused machine at hand, you could try to install only Windows and MSVC and test whether you have that problem. I would suspect a too clever driver or application somewhere in the machine...

Comment: n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.  :   I am well aware of the different encoding system, Have made several application handling this kind of problem
using CP-1252 and/or IEC 8859-1  and/or UTF-8
If you don't like to call CP-1252 for ANSI is up to you. I don't care.
My question is about a specific problem I have during debugging . Not about variation in character coding since the text files I am reading is using "ANSI"

Comment: Yeah it was just a nitpick that grew out of proportion, sorry. I guess your source code uses CP-1252, so the characters in the program end up being CP-1252 characters, but the VS debugger has no way of knowing that. It may or may interpret them as UTF-8, which is of course wrong, but AFAIK there is no setting to tell it to use something else. Try to reencode your source as UTF-8 (with BOM) and recompile, and see if you still have this problem. (Of course your Swedish characters won't be one byte any more).

Comment: You may need to add `/utf-8` compiler switch (makes both source and execution charset UTF-8), or use separate `/source-charset` and `/execution-charset` switches.

Comment: "there is no setting to tell it to use something else"      
The debugger does not have to know anything special.     All it needs to do is to display the string and replace anything it does not "understand" with a '�

Comment: I didn't write the debugger. It does what it does. If you don't like it, file a bug report to Microsoft (yeah right).